# Create dynamic image slider in umbraco without using plugins

Tags: html, css, dynamic, slider, umbraco

I am using Umbraco 7. Currently I am working on making the image slider. I created the document type celeb wall and created the template celeb. Now I need to use the code between article tags with id="slider" and make the images captions loop:

I have created the property slider with the type as media picker and sliderBanner as textstring.

The page needs to be dynamically like the link below:

http://newmilkshakecity.appspot.com/

Can you please help me, please?

Ronny

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix it and make it dynamic. It took me quite few days to get to grips with creating slider using ASP.Net MVC on Umbraco Platform.

N.B. The slider was quite an old piece of code, where I used article to wrap the slider when I could have used div and then ul and li tag. However, this was a good experience.